# How to get notification if someone posts on linkedin. Is there any webhook APIs linkedIn provides

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, webhooks, social-networking

I am looking for a webhook API so that my server will be notified if someone does something related to my company's page.

Like [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started), [Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started), [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/guides/getting-started-with-webhooks.html) provides a [Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-webhook/) API concept, but I cannot find the same thing with [LinkedIn APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs).

I have seen some websites which do the same but I don't know how they are doing, are they keep syncing the contents from LinkedIn or making API calls again & again or what.

Answer (score 2):

You can use webhooks as explained in their docs -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-social-action-notifications?tabs=http#webhook-registration-and-validation